# Transfering posts from M1 AW Blog to M2 Amasty Blog Pro

Tags: sql, magento

I need to move all blog posts from Magento 1 with Aheadworks Blog extension to Magento 2 with Amasty Blog Pro extension.

Did anyone allready try this?

It would be very helpful to get the correct sql statement for either direction, i.e. getting the old posts out of M1 and/or getting them into M2. Then I could write a short script doing the transfer on a database level.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity http://magento.stackexchange.com also does not allow this type of question as its related to third party module

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala - Good to know. I'm not as keenly aware of the rules there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I have seen many posts on magento.stackexchange.com related to 3rd-party modules and nothing indicating that they are disallowed, so you might still want to try there.  That aside, I am in the process of moving from Aheadworx Blog for M1 to a different M2 blog extension and it is no picnic.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at the tables created in both instances, compare columns and datatypes, then write your update script.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

> As this related to third party module this is off topic question but
>   still I give you the logic

As of now there is no way you can migrate this blog, if they have same database structure then you can easily migrate those data using Magento [data-migration-tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-install.html), But I think those two are separate extension so might be they have different table structure.

So for this what you can do is mapp tables which fields you want from which table and craete standalone PHP file(not magento) and create 2 database connection and fetch data from one table and insert in other

That's the only way to do so